# What are the approaches for converting SNAPSHOT to milestone?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to set a milestone in an existing sbt project using sbt 0.12 inside a script.

In Apache Maven, I'd use the `mvn versions:set Version=foo` approach using [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html) to create a semver-compliant version.

I'd appreciate some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### sbt-release plugin's way

Use [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin that [follows the semantic versioning scheme on semver.org](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#requirements).

### set and session save

Given [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090842/what-are-the-approaches-for-converting-snapshot-to-milestone/25093248?noredirect=1#comment39106816_25093248) where you've asked about *something similar to a "mvn versions:set Version=foo" function I can call from a script.* it should be ease with *no* additional plugins - it's a built-in feature of sbt - settings.

`show` displays the value of the specified setting. In your case, it's `version`.

```
➜  sbt-learning-space  sbt "show version"
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] 0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The current version in the build is `0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Let's change it to `1.0.0` with `set` that applies the given setting to the current project.

```
➜  sbt-learning-space  sbt 'set version := "1.0.0"'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] Defining *:version
[info] The new value will be used by *:isSnapshot, *:projectId and 3 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
```

It does not automatically persist the setting(s).

```
➜  sbt-learning-space  sbt "show version"
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] 0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

You should run `session save` or `session save-all` to make the session settings permanent by writing them to a `.sbt` configuration file.

```
➜  sbt-learning-space  sbt 'set version := "1.0.0"' 'session save'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] Defining *:version
[info] The new value will be used by *:isSnapshot, *:projectId and 3 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
```

With `session save` the value of `version` got persisted to `build.sbt` file.

```
➜  sbt-learning-space  sbt "show version"
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/)
[info] 1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in that direction. I'm still pretty new to SBT, so I'm still struggling a bit. I followed the README and added the sbt-release to my plugins.sbt, and it pulled in the jar. What I'm having problems with is actually invoking the plugin. For example, if I wanted to have the plugin generate the version.sbt file with a given version and then read it at build time, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to a "mvn versions:set Version=foo" function I can call from a script.

Comment: You asked and I provided a solution that should meet your "script" requirement. Approve when helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. This worked well for me. I'm new on stack overflow and don't have permissions to upvote this yet, but as soon as I do I'll come back. Thanks again.